# MYSQL TIMESTAMPDIFF function is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timestampdiff

I am trying to use TIMESTAMPDIFF function in one of my queries and is making an headache for me.

**TABLE**

```
id  |  web_address    |  timeperiod  |  timeperiod_exp

1   |  www.google.com |  1564692614  |  1564779014
```

> 1564692614 = GMT: Thursday, August 1, 2019 8:50:14 PM
>
> 1564779014 = GMT: Friday, August 2, 2019 8:50:14 PM

**WHATS THE PROBLEM ?**

As one can see the difference between these two timestamps is exactly 1 day but is returning no records.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, timeperiod, timeperiod_exp) >= 1
```

**WHERE IS THE FIDDLE ?**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/udmrC2xdvrEEKGxEF7ty84/7

**WHAT SHOULD BE DONE ?**

Please take a look at the fiddle above and suggest what should be modified or other function in place of timestampdiff.

Comment: It's a good thing to provide a fiddle. But you should always include everything necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself, not only in a fiddle. The fiddle  possibly gets down and then the question is useless.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks i ll update it here also. Can you please look at the problem its really a long time since this is giving me problem

Comment: You're inserting four rows where for each row just one column is filled, so there is no row where both `timeperiod` and `timeperiod_and` are filled. And `timeperiod` and `timeperiod_exp` are `integer`s, not `timestamp`s.

Comment: Remove the WHERE clause and [see what you get](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/enVQ67m37VPLsMAZDWNcjx/0). Then go and read about [INSERT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

Comment: i have got it the insert syntax i am using fiddle for the first time ever thanks for pointing that out and check the updated fiddle now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

> TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)
>
> Returns datetime_expr2 − datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and
>   datetime_expr2 are date or datetime expressions. One expression may be
>   a date and the other a datetime

As you see, it expects the parameters to be of type DATE or DATETIME. But you have your timestamps stored as integers.

So either use [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert your integer timestamps to DATETIME:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, FROM_UNIXTIME(timeperiod), FROM_UNIXTIME(timeperiod_exp)) >= 1
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uXVD4PCctxVqYvPXyKCws5/0)

Or just use simple arithmetics (since we know how many seconds are in one day):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (timeperiod_exp - timeperiod) >= 60*60*24
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tUqUvGX3unW8bia39GD866/0)

Comment: Thanks for that info it was making an headache.

Comment: One question how can i select record where timestamp is not between today?

Comment: "not between today" - what does that mean? Probably `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timeperiod)) <> CURRENT_DATE()`.

Answer (score 0):

As if i see the function TIMESTAMPDIFF() should take two timestamps but it is taking dates instead of direct timestamps in integers Thus the following works:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, FROM_UNIXTIME(timeperiod), FROM_UNIXTIME(timeperiod_exp)) >= 1
```

**Updated Fiddle**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/udmrC2xdvrEEKGxEF7ty84/8